# using checkbox in data grid view

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

below picture is taken from a ready software. 
I want to prepare a data grid like this. How can I insert a checkbox in a coloumn of data grid  in C#?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select column type DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to create a templatefield column for gridview like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvTxnPermission" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" >
                            <ControlStyle Width="200px" />
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Permission" AccessibleHeaderText="Permission">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="100px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

after that you can bind your data inside gridview like that:

```
 private void BindToDataGridView(DataTable dataTable) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < alTxnTypeId.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dataTable.Rows[j].ItemArray[1].ToString() == alTxnTypeId[i].ToString())
                {
                    (dgvTxnPermission.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox).Checked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT: that code is : part of the my sample project. Just i compied and pasted without modify. So, dont mind about details like CssClass etc, and the other things. just understand my sample code..